# Laravel 6 Process class relies on proc_open exception

Tags: laravel

- Laravel Version: 6
- PHP Version: 7.3

#### Description:

After installing Laravel 6, i get the following error message:

`The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.`

I don't have find anything in the docs about this?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of Flare error reporting service enabled in debug mode
There is a workaround for this.

Publish flare config file
`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=flare-config`

and in config/flare.php

Set

```
'collect_git_information' => false
```

```
'reporting' => [
        'anonymize_ips' => true,
        'collect_git_information' => false,
        'report_queries' => true,
        'maximum_number_of_collected_queries' => 200,
        'report_query_bindings' => true,
        'report_view_data' => true,
    ],
```